# Ruby on Rails - How to execute js code when view contains certain div?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In our team it is practice to keep all Javascript in their own .js files -> no Javascript in Views.

Certain events cause new divs to be loaded on the page (but the page itself does not get reloaded, nor do we go to a new URL). I want the Javascript code only to be executed when a certain div is loaded.

My current solution is to simply call within the view:

```
<script>
  someJavascriptFunction(...);
</script>
```

What I want is something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my-div").....
}
```

However, `$(document).ready`, only loads once. Same for

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
   //some function
});
```

which only seems to work when the URL actually changes.

Does somebody have an good idea on how to execute Javascript only when a certain div is currently loaded on the page/in the current view?

I haven't found a working solution yet...

Hopefully my question is clear - I'm new to Javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using default turoblinks:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("#my-div").....
});
```

[RoR turbolinks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks)